# Get data from angular linker form

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template

I have problem like this:
I have list item, each item after selected  will have a subset of form to fill out, data will be save to database. Howerver, each form has different link ( link forms are provided by the third). 
I need solution to pop-up there forms and get data from them.
Thanks many times.

Comment: you ask the user to add the link to the form, the user fills the rest of the form, and when submitted you pass the link of the form to your service where it makes request to that link to save the data, is this what you want ?

Comment: No, I mean the form are provided by the third, not by user.
When user choose  item, content of the form pop-up will depend on which item they choose.

Comment: take a look at reactive forms, you will be able to achieve what you want once you follow the guide, just make different variables for each form and when a user select item change the selected form:
https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: if it's hard for you i can guide you with an answer here

Comment: @Hussein Thanks for your help, but that is not what I need. The third only gave me the link to their form, nothing more. 
You can image that: you come to anther website, fill their form, and your website can get all data you fill in the form.

Comment: that doesn't work in angular alone